# Testing EmailMessage json in gmail

Tags: google-schemas

I also do not see the button in my test emails to myself. It is in a gmail account.  Does the script tag have to come directly after the body tag? The email tester https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/ says the emails good and pulls out the script tag fine.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "description": "Answer",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "testuri",
    "name": "Survey"
  },
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Orgname",
    "url": "https://www.Orgurl",
    "url/googlePlus": "https://plus.google.com/+Orgname/posts"
  }
}

</script>
```

For testing does it matter if it is a via?
"@gmail.com via amazonses.com"

I have the correct security stuff setup per the suggested testing. I see

mailed-by:   amazonses.com and 
signed-by:   amazonses.com

Comment: Try sending the same email via the Apps Script method described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/apps-script-tutorial) to eliminate signing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I set it up. I was pretty easy. Using app scripts with the same HTML from my email the link does show up for my gmail account.   

|edited| Sorry not use to shift enter

Should I be concerned that the testing didn't work with amazonses? Will this be a problem once its white listed? 

Thanks!

Comment: No, I think it's a limitation of the testing mode. In testing mode we only process the markup is from yourself to yourself, and I think your code isn't setting the correct headers to verify that it's really from you (vs. a spoof).